# Logging from multiple processes to same log file with Log4Cplus (Windows)

Tags: log4cplus

The way some of our clients use our application is to install onto a network drive and then each user executes the exe on their local machine. Because of this we have multiple processes writing to the same log file. I've tested this configuration out with some test programs and I'm getting this error.

```
log4cplus:ERROR Failed to rename file from ../Log.log to ../Log.log.1; error 13
```

I'm assuming this is due to the file being written to when one of the processes logger tries to rename it.

Here is my properties file.

```
log4cplus.logger.TESTLOGGER=ALL, TESTAPPENDER
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER.CreateDirs=true
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER.File=../Log.log
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER.UseLockFile=true
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4cplus.appender.TESTAPPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

My question is is if Log4Cplus has a way to handle this, or is this just a generic no-go with logging? Would using the AsyncAppender work? If so, could you give an example of how to use it? I cannot find any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue Windows and how `fstream` and its `streambuf` opens the file. From issue [#167](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/bugs/167/#0367):

> Basically, the problem is that the underlying Win32 file `HANDLE` is not open with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag. This flag, beside shared delete, allows renaming files that have handles open to them.

So, bottom line is that it is solvable but creating own `streambuf` out of nothing with all the necessary support for `codecvt` facet is so hard that I have never finished it.